# WSJ jar from sphinx4-beta5 is incompatible with WSJ jar from sphinx4-beta6

Tags: netbeans, sphinx4

I've installed Sphinxbase and sphinx4-1.0beta6 by following all the instructions of the [official site](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx). I opened the Sphinx4 folder as a Netbeans project and I built it succesfully, but when running the HelloWorld example I got the error above:

```
Exception in thread "main" Property exception component:'dictionary' property:'fillerPath'     
Can't locate resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz/noisedict edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.InternalConfigurationException
```

I added the WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.jar to the classpath using the .jar file that belongs to sphinx4-1.0beta5 version, because in the beta6 version it was inexistent.

Can someone please throw me some light?

--

I think the problem is related with the config.xml

```
<component name="dictionary"
    type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.dictionary.FastDictionary">
    <property name="dictionaryPath" value="resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz/dict/cmudict.0.6d"/>
    <property name="fillerPath" value="resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz/noisedict"/>
    <property name="addSilEndingPronunciation" value="false"/>
    <property name="allowMissingWords" value="false"/>
    <property name="unitManager" value="unitManager"/>
</component>
```

Because inside WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.jar I only see the packages cd_continuous_8gau, dict and etc.

Comment: You need to use WSJ...jar from beta6, not from beta5. Beta6 also creates such jar when you run build process with `ant`. You just need to run build in Netbeans and the proper jar will be created in lib folder. Alternatively you can download a binary distribution for beta6, it also contains required jar.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, problem solved (although I'd to change to beta 5). But now I'm having problems with the microphone in linux (in W7 works fine).

Answer (score -1):

Ok, just copy the content of helloworld.config.xml from sphinx4-1.0beta5 version(beta6 is buggy).